# Ask turtles to face set of patches with highest summed value

Tags: netlogo

I am working in NetLogo on an animal movement model. I have created six different agentsets that contain the patches in-cone 16 60 (asking my turtles to turn rt 60 before calculating the next agentset). I have then asked each agentset to calculate the sum of weighted-index (a patch variable between 0-1) and save the value into a global variable. So now I gave six areas surrounding each turtle, and a value that represents the resource value of that entire agentset to the turtle. I am trying to get my turtles to recognize what agentset has the highest sum of the weighted index and move to a random patch within it. I am running into issues because the global variable that represents the summed weighted index is not attached to the location of the agentset so I don't know how to move on from this step. My only idea is to do a complicated ifelse chain where I ask turtles to compare the summed values and face the agentset corresponding to that value, but this seems pretty lengthy. Any ideas or suggestions on how to solve this or make my question clearer are much appreciated!

I have tried to make a list and call for with-max but again, this reports the max sum as a number, not the agentset to which it belongs to.

```
; This code gets called in my go procedure as ask bears []
;I am first creating the agentsets
  set heading 0
  set n-patches patches in-cone 16 60
  rt 60
  set ne-patches patches in-cone 16 60
  rt 60
  set se-patches patches in-cone 16 60
  rt 60    
  set s-patches patches in-cone 16 60
  rt 60    
  set sw-patches patches in-cone 16 60
  rt 60    
  set nw-patches patches in-cone 16 60

; Now I'm adding the index value for all patches within each agentset
  set n-sum sum [weighted-index] of n-patches
  set ne-sum sum [weighted-index] of ne-patches
  set se-sum sum [weighted-index] of se-patches
  set s-sum sum [weighted-index] of s-patches
  set sw-sum sum [weighted-index] of sw-patches
  set nw-sum sum [weighted-index] of nw-patches

; Lost after this
```

Comment: Not sure why this was down-voted, perfectly clear question

Answer (score 1):

First thing, there's no need to use global variables, just use `let` to create a temporary local variable.

This is a surprisingly tricky problem because you can't use any of the built in primitives that find the maximum within an agentset and list primitives don't have that capability.

I have written a standalone model that demonstrates what you want. It uses `pcolor` as the value instead of the weighted index, and I chose colours that get darker as the number increases.

```
to testme
  clear-all
  ask patches [ set pcolor one-of [ 28 54 110 ] ]
  create-turtles 3
  [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set color white
  ]
  ask turtles
  [ set heading 0
    let n-patches patches in-cone 16 60
    rt 60
    let ne-patches patches in-cone 16 60
    rt 60
    let se-patches patches in-cone 16 60
    rt 60
    let s-patches patches in-cone 16 60
    rt 60
    let sw-patches patches in-cone 16 60
    rt 60
    let nw-patches patches in-cone 16 60 
    let directions-list shuffle (list n-patches ne-patches se-patches s-patches sw-patches nw-patches)
    print directions-list
    let sums-list map [ thisDir -> sum [pcolor] of thisDir ] directions-list
    print sums-list
    let max-sums max sums-list
    print max-sums
    let chosen position max-sums sums-list
    print chosen
    face one-of item chosen directions-list
  ]
end
```

You could use a `to-report` procedures to simplify the calculation of the six agentsets, but I haven't done that as I wanted to use your code to help keep it readable

This prints things out so you can see what it's doing. Note that the `shuffle` is to ensure random selection if 2 or more happen to have the same totals. Remember that NetLogo lists are 0-indexed, so `position` will return 0 to 5, not 1 to 6.

What it does is puts the agentsets into a list, calculates the value of the sums (using `map`) for each item on the list and puts those sums into a new list in the same order. It then searches for the maximum of that new list, finds the position of that maximum, uses that position to extract the correct agentset from the first list, and then faces a random patch within that agentset.

Comment: Hi JenB, thank you so much for you answer. I modified my code (see below) and it seems to be working for now. I'm going to be adding more complexity so your suggestions will come in handy. My code now: Sum index by using "let n-sum sum [perceived-index] of patches in-cone 16 60", repeat for each quadrant asking turtles to turn 60 between calculation. Then use "let max-sum max (list (n-sum) (ne-sum) (se-sum) (s-sum) (sw-sum) (nw-sum))" to find the max, then "ifelse n-sum = max-sum [set heading 0 move]" and repeat for each quadrant.